# Setting file permissions in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, file, permissions

I managed to get my hands on a nifty ftp object. It is very low level and easy to adapt. I'm using it to transfer files from one Mac to another via FTP.

Now, the issue I'm having is that when the file, that is transfered, reaches its destination, the other Mac, the access permissions is set , at random intervals, to "Everyone" : "No Access". So sometimes, whatever I do with the files fails randomly because my application can't access the files.

Is there a way I can change the file's access permissions in Objective-C?

Regards,
EZFrag

Comment: change the remote file's access permissions?

Comment: Nope. Change the local file's permissions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For permissons of local files, you'd want [`[NSFileManager setAttributes:ofItemAtPath:error:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/setAttributes%3aofItemAtPath%3aerror%3a)

And the attribute dictionary you'd want to use would include [`NSFilePosixPermissions`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/data/NSFilePosixPermissions).

Comment: `NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];`   
`[dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:511]  forKey:NSFilePosixPermissions]; /*511 is Decimal for the 777 octal*/`     
   
`NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];`   
  
`NSError *error1;`   
`[fm setAttributes:dict ofItemAtPath:[file path] error:&error1];`

Comment: @Michael , I am doing the same for modifying the  NSFileGroupOwnerAccountID. but it is not updating, giving cocoaerrorcode513 error.     [attributes setValue:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLong:12345]forKey:NSFileGroupOwnerAccountID];

Comment: @EZFrag It is not working when I tried to set the permission for a folder inside \Library\ColorSync\