# Is there any way to programmatically modify file permisson(read/write) in Mac OSX?

Tags: objective-c, macos, file-permissions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Setting file permissions in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257630/setting-file-permissions-in-objective-c)

I want to apply read/write permission for a file based on some scenario.

Is there any way to programmatically modify file permisson(read/write) in Mac OSX?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Pragmatically or programmatically? Which language are you using?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257630/setting-file-permissions-in-objective-c

Answer (score 0):

This is the snippet I use every time:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]; 

int r = 04; // read
int w = 02; // write
int x = 01; // execute

int owner = (r | w | x) * (8 * 8);
int group = (r | w)         * (8);
int other = (x);

int permissions = owner + group + other;

[dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:permissions] forKey:NSFilePosixPermissions]; 

NSError *error = nil;
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] setAttributes:dict ofItemAtPath:[file path] error:&error];
```

This makes the file read/write/execute-able for the owner, read/write-able for the group and executable for other.

Just adapt your permission settings…

Comment: Style: if you're going to use octal values for `r`, `w`, and `x`, use `0100` and `010` instead of `8*8` and `8` too.  (Though sadly, I think octal probably just confuses most people these days).

Comment: I'm using octal numbers and then I shift them. Don't know what you mean?

Comment: I know exactly what you mean.  FWIW, you *don't* shift them, you multiply them (which is equivalent in this case).  It would be cleaner stylistically if you used octal for all of the literals instead of mixing octal and decimal.

Comment: Ah OK, now I've got it, thanks ; )

Comment: @septi Its throwing error when tried to change the permission for one of the folder in \Library\ (not ~\Library\) , But we are able to do the same manually.